# how to use jquery validate .js in wordpress for user name already exist?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, validation

Hi I am making a registration form in my `WordPress` site

this is the code:

in `register.php`

```
  php starting  
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ $reg_result = reg_register();
   php ending

<form method="post" action="" name="registerform" id="register-form">
<label class="reg_lable_style">Name</label>
<input name="fname" class="r_text span12 required" type="text">
<label class="reg_lable_style">email</label>
<input name="email" id="email" class="r_text span12 required email" type="text"  >
<label class="reg_lable_style">password</label>
<input name="psd" id="psd" class="r_text span12 required" type="text"  >
<input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

in `functions.php`

```
function reg_register(){

$user_name=esc_attr(stripslashes($_POST['uname']));
$user_email=esc_attr(stripslashes($_POST['email']));
$pass=$_POST['psd'];
$userdata = array(
     'user_login'    =>  $user_name,
        'user_email'  => $user_email,
        'user_pass' =>  $pass
);

 $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;

}
```

in `footer.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');?>/js/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#register-form').validate();
   </script>
```

My registration form is working correctly with validation. (i.e. this field is required, please enter a valid emial etc)
Now i need to make a validation that this username is already exists.  How to do that. Please help

Comment: Have you read the documentation yet?  That would be a good place to start.  Rules, options, etc. go inside of your `.validate()` call.

Answer (score 0):

On the server side you can validate wether or not a user exists by using the

```
username_exists($username);
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/username_exists.

In addition, inserting a user manually into the database is not recommended as WordPress provides an interface for this functionality via

```
wp_create_user( $username, $password, $email );
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_user

To see how to implement it in validate.js (you need output the desired javascript , it via php), see
http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/milk/

Comment: i know this function username_exists($username); .Currently i used this also. But  i need to work it as other validation like valid email etc.Now it is in checked after form submission.I want to do this before form submission.Really Thanks for valuable answer